# Increase oAuth 100 user cap while Google API App is under review?

Tags: google-api

Is there an email contact at Google to get our Google API App's oAuth user cap raised from 100 to say 500?  Our app has been in the review process for almost a month already.  Until it's verified, none of our new customers can connect to their YouTube accounts.  This app has been in production for over 5 years with many thousands of customers connected already.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue?